# Getting error in connection class while sending url having lots of parameters

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection, nsxmlparser

Hello Friends i am getting a problem in connection class i am using the same connection class for my different methods .Every where its working fine but on making this particular connection i m getting error ie:..  Connection did fail with error.

I am posting my entire code please help me.
**Code for sending my url and making connection:-**

```
 NSString *strURl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://xxxyyy.com/API/index.php?action=listIt&login=%@&pwd=%@&name=%@&catID=%d&listID=&addr1=%@&addr2=%@&locName=&city=%@&state=%@&zip=&startDate=%@&startHours=%@&startMin=%@&startMeridiem=%@&endDate=%@&endHours=%@&endMin=%@&endMeridiem=%@&contactName=&contactPhone=&contactEmail=&contactWebsite=&cost=%d&description=%@",appDelegate.strUserName,appDelegate.strPassword,strTitle,self.subCat_ID,[txtAddress1.text urlEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],[txtAdress2.text urlEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],lblCity.text,lblState.text,strBeginDate,startHr,startMin,startMeridiem,strEndDate,strEndHr,strEndMin,strEndMeridiem,cost,[txtdDscription.text urlEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

            //strURl=[strURl urlEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
           // NSString *strEncode=[strURl stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
           // strEncode=[strEncode stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
            NSLog(@" strListItURl  =%@",strURl);
            ConnectionClass *connection=[[ConnectionClass alloc]init];
            [connection getResponseData:strURl];
            connection.delegate=self;
            [connection release];
```

**NSLog(@" strListItURl  =%@",strURl); this is the url with method and parameter i am sending.** 
strListItURl http://xxxyyy.com/API/index.php?action=listIt&login=sawanth&pwd=sawanth&name=Hello One&catID=4&listID=&addr1=One%20tow&addr2=next%20one&locName=&city=Anchorage&state=Alaska&zip=&startDate=11/8/2012&startHours=11&startMin=33&startMeridiem=AM&endDate=11/10/2012&endHours=11&endMin=33&endMeridiem=AM&contactName=&contactPhone=&contactEmail=&contactWebsite=&cost=3&description=%20Hello

**Note:-when i am pasting the "strListItURl" directly on browser i am getting success.**

**Now after making connection i am entering in connection class**

```
-(void)getResponseData:(NSString*)strURL
{

    NSLog(@"strURL =%@",strURL);
 //   NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strURL];
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]; 
    NSLog(@"url is =%@",strURL);   

    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:30.0];
    //Initialize the connection for NSURL Connection
    theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
    if(theConnection)
    {
        //Initialize the data and retain the data
        receiveData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Please check internet connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

    }


}
```

**here when i m printing urlRequest  i am finding**
Printing description of urlRequest: NSURLRequest (null)

And finaly controls goes to 
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error

please tell me where i am doing wrong:)

Comment: [an error occurred while processing this directive]

Answer (score 0):

You havent alloc the NSURLRequest. But it is strange it is printing null instead of nil.

Try:

```
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:30.0];
```

Comment: damn, could you nslog [urlRequest url]? I wonder if it is setting it. Otherwise use POST instead of a GET?

Answer (score 0):

**I got the answer.
Actually when i was passing the strURL**

```
NSString *strURl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://xxxyyy.com/API/index.php?action=listIt&login=%@&pwd=%@&name=%@&catID=%d&listID=&addr1=%@&addr2=%@&locName=&city=%@&state=%@&zip=&startDate=%@&startHours=%@&startMin=%@&startMeridiem=%@&endDate=%@&endHours=%@&endMin=%@&endMeridiem=%@&contactName=&contactPhone=&contactEmail=&contactWebsite=&cost=%d&description=%@",appDelegate.strUserName,appDelegate.strPassword,strTitle,self.subCat_ID,[txtAddress1.text urlEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],[txtAdress2.text urlEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],lblCity.text,lblState.text,strBeginDate,startHr,startMin,startMeridiem,strEndDate,strEndHr,strEndMin,strEndMeridiem,cost,[txtdDscription.text urlEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

**its taking blank space from somewhere ,and due to this my connection just fail with error.
so i trimmed the blank spaces**

```
strURl = [strURl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

and its start working fine.